# Simulate mouse clicks from keyboard on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, mouse

I like to play some games on my Mac but tend to bind mouse clicks to the keyboard to be more silent late at night. In many games you can adjust these bindings from game settings, but not in all games. Is there a more general OS way to simulate mouse clicks using the keyboard that would work in all games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. It is available in the Universal Access preference pane in the Mouse tab. This is off by default so you need to turn it on.

Clicking the '?' in the lower right of the window will explain how to use it.